# Using rdb$get_context as default value for a column

Tags: dns, firebird, default-value

In a Firebird database, I need to create a `DOMAIN` with default value taken from the context variable.

It should be something like

```
CREATE DOMAIN USER_ID AS INTEGER 
  DEFAULT RDB$GET_CONTEXT('USER_SESSION','UID') NOT NULL;
```

When I execute this, I am getting the following error

> Invalid token.
>   Dynamic SQL Error.
>   SQL error code = -104.
>   Token unknown - line 2, column 13.
>   RDB$GET_CONTEXT.

How can this be done, maybe there is another way than the `DEFAULT` clause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create a BEFORE INSERT trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER your_trigger_name FOR your_table
  BEFORE INSERT
  POSITION 0
AS
BEGIN
  IF (NEW.your_field IS NULL) THEN
    NEW.your_field = RDB$GET_CONTEXT('USER_SESSION','UID'); 
END
```

Comment: Thanks I wanted to not have to create a trigger for each table. Firebird does not support this. Thanks